# CSS нестандартные шрифты

Tags: шрифты, html, css

Добрый день, верстальщик из меня довольно плохой, вот поэтому и спрашиваю, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как сделать кроссбраузерно чтобы в html при помощи css, внедрять нестандартные шрифты, которые могут быть и неустановлены, у пользователя сайта, пока вот что нашёл, не знаю насколько это верное решение

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Scriptorama; /* имя шрифта для CSS правил */
    src: local("Scriptorama"), /* проверяем наличие шрифта в ОС пользователя */
         url(path-to/Scriptorama.ttf); 
  }
```

Вопрос: как с такой задачей нужно бороться? Насколько верно моё решение и будет ли оно работать на основных современных браузера?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прогоните ваш шрифт через [шрифтобелку](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), как вам посоветовали выше.
В полученном архиве будет файл стилей, из которого вы скопируете @font-face-правило в свою таблицу стилей

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lobster_1.4regular';
    src: url('lobster-webfont.eot');
    src: url('lobster-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lobster-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lobster-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lobster-webfont.svg#lobster_1.4regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

*Не забудьте поправить пути к вашей папке, где лежит шрифт
В большинстве случаев этого будет достаточно, чтобы шрифт заработал.
Иногда бывает нужно выбрать в шрифтобелке режим EXPERT, чтобы задать какие-то конкретные настройки шрифтов.

Comment: Спасибо! Все кто ответил очень помогли!

Answer (score 3):

Ваше решение верное, однако нужно иметь ввиду, что разные браузеры предпочитают шрифты разных форматов: TTF, OTF, EOT, SVG и WOFF.
 1. Internet Explorer (все версии) — EOT;
 2. Firefox (начиная с 3.5) — TTF/OTF (WOFF добавлен с версии 3.6);
 3. Opera (начиная с 10) — TTF/OTF;
 4. Chrome (все версии) — SVG (TTF/OTF добавлены в конце января 2010-го);
 5. Safari (начиная с 3.2) — TTF/OTF.

Не спешите отчаиваться, существуют ряд сервисов позволяющих генерировать выбранный Вами шрифт сразу в несколько форматов, например [этот](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).